# Visual Studio Xamarin iOS ThreadAccessException calling a Task UIKit method

Tags: c#, ios, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm newbie in Xamarin. I'm developing a Xamarin iOS and Android app sharing code by using PCL. Into PCL library I've implemented following class model that uses a get Web API with HttpClient:

```
public class NorthwindModel : INorthWindModel
{
    public event ChangeStatusEventHandler ChangeStatus;

    public async Task<IProduct> GetProductByIDAsync(int ID)
    {
        using (var Client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            Product product = null;

            Client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://testjson.com/webapi/northwind/");
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // Notificar aqui que la API Web será invocada
            ChangeStatus?.Invoke(this, new ChangeStatusEventArgs() { Status = StatusOptions.CallingWebAPI });

            HttpResponseMessage Response = await Client.GetAsync($"product/{ID}");

            // Notificar aquí que se va a verificar el resultado de la llamada
            ChangeStatus?.Invoke(this, new ChangeStatusEventArgs() { Status = StatusOptions.VerifyingResult });

            if (Response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var JSONProduct = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(JSONProduct);

                if (product != null)
                {
                    ChangeStatus?.Invoke(this, new ChangeStatusEventArgs() { Status = StatusOptions.ProductFound });
                }
                else
                {
                    ChangeStatus?.Invoke(this, new ChangeStatusEventArgs() { Status = StatusOptions.ProductNotFound });
                }
            }

            return product;
        }
    }
}
```

in the Xamarin iOS poject, in the viewController.cs I've implemented a button event to find the product:

```
partial void BtnFind_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() => model.GetProductByIDAsync(int.Parse(txtID.Text)));

        product = task.Result;

        if (product != null)
        {
            txtNombre.Text = product.ProductName;
            txtPrecio.Text = $"{product.UnitPrice:0,000.00}";
            txtExistencia.Text = $"{product.UnitsInStock:0,000}";
            txtCategoria.Text = product.CategoryID.ToString();
        }
    }
```

When I try to run in Visual Studio 2017 for Windows, for some reason VS get freezed and locked and I have to kill VS. When I try to execute in VS for MAC, I get the following exception:

ThreadAccessException you're calling a Task UIKit method that can only be invoked in the UI Thread

Please your help!

Comment: The duplicate question covers the UI thread consistency error, but as to your freeze - this is because you are calling Task.Result. Calling this on a UI thread will cause your app to freeze. The better way is to use async/await - in it's simplest for for your example mark you method as async then await the task.

Comment: Thanks JimBobBennett! the solution was to mark the TouchUpInside event as async and call the task by using await.

Comment: Glad it worked - ideally though your model method should be async and return a task that you await to save spinning up a new task in the event handler